# Binary representation over serial Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary, pyserial

I'm writing various bytes over serial in the form of ascii representations.

Heres an example: `bytes_to_write = '\aa' # Will write 01010101`

Now one part of what I send involves me calculating the 4 bytes that need to be transferred, I calculate the bytes using the below function:

```
def convert_addr_with_flag(addr, flag):
    if(addr[0:1]!="0x"):
        # String does not have hex start, for representation
        addr = "0x" + addr
    # Convert String to int
    return binascii.unhexlify(str(hex(int(addr, 16) + (flag << 31))[2:].zfill(8)))  # Return the int value, bit shiffted with flag
```

This function will return a binary string instead of an ascii string however. Here is an example...
`convert_addr_with_flag("00ACFF21", 1) # Output: b'\x80\xac\xff!'`

My question is how I can get this output to a form that I can add to the other bytes of the packet. e.g..

```
part_1 = '\xaa\xaa' # 2 bytes
part_2 = '\x55\x55' # 2 bytes
part_3 = convert_addr_with_flag("00ACFF21", 1) # 4 bytes
full_packet = part_1 + part_2 + part_3 # Will not work, as part_3 is a binary string (b'\x80\xac\xff!)
```

Heres what I have already tried,
using `decode("UTF-8)` and UTF-16 and ASCII. It cannot understand the byte string.
Slicing. using [2] give me a binary character, but not the 'second byte'

Any tips would be very much appreciated!

**Python 3.4**

Comment: Have you considered the pickle module?  It allows you to send data over the wire (files, sockets) and will reconstruct the data for you as well.

Comment: Unfortunately I'll need to send exact binary over the wire, Interesting module though, it could come handy in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`decode` isn't working because there is no ascii representation of `part_3`; an ascii character must be an int between 0 and 127 inclusive. It looks like `part_3` in this example is `b'\x80\xac\xff!'`; the first three bytes are 128, 172 and 255, none of which are valid ascii.

If you need to send bytes that aren't between 0 and 127, you will probably need `part_1` and `part_2` to be byte strings.

Comment: I've taken the approach to create all parts of my packet as bytes objects. I think this will work as long as pyserial allows for writing raw bytes instead of encoded strings